# How to create Hybrid loss consisting from dice loss and focal loss [Python]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to implement the **Multiclass Hybrid loss** function in Python from following article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05238.pdf  for my **semantic segmentation** problem using an imbalanced dataset. I managed to get my implementation correct enough to start while training the model, but the results are very poor. Model architecture - **U-net**, learning rate in **Adam** optimizer is **1e-5**. Mask shape is (None, 512, 512, 3), with 3 classes (in my case forest, deforestation, other). The formula I used to implement my loss:
[image]

The code I created:

```
def build_hybrid_loss(_lambda_=1, _alpha_=0.5, _beta_=0.5, smooth=1e-6):
    def hybrid_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        C = 3
        tversky = 0
        # Calculate Tversky Loss
        for index in range(C):
            inputs_fl = tf.nest.flatten(y_pred[..., index])
            targets_fl = tf.nest.flatten(y_true[..., index])
        
            #True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
            TP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(inputs_fl, targets_fl))
            FP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(inputs_fl, 1-targets_fl[0]))
            FN = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(1-inputs_fl[0], targets_fl))
           
            tversky_i = (TP + smooth) / (TP + _alpha_ * FP + _beta_ * FN + smooth)  
            tversky += tversky_i
        tversky += C
        
        # Calculate Focal loss
        loss_focal = 0
        for index in range(C):
            f_loss = - (y_true[..., index] * (1 - y_pred[..., index])**2 * tf.math.log(y_pred[..., index]))
            # Average over each data point/image in batch
            axis_to_reduce = range(1, 3)
            f_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(f_loss, axis=axis_to_reduce)
            loss_focal += f_loss
            
        result = tversky + _lambda_ * loss_focal
        return result
    return hybrid_loss
```

The prediction of the model after the end of an epoch (I have a problem with **swapped colors**, so the red in the prediction is actually green, which means forest, so the prediction is mostly forest and not deforestation):
[image]

The question is what is wrong with my hybrid loss implementation, what needs to be changed to make it work?

Comment: `I have a problem with swapped colors` : if you are using opencv, note that the default color space is `BGR`, while other image manipulation libraries tends to work with `RGB`.

Comment: @Lescurel, when I started the project I made my Class 1 = Forest (color green) and the `prediction[..., 0]` is the predicted mask for the forest. But when I use `plt.imshow(prediction)` the prediction has three channels just like the RGB image and so the first mask (forest mask) is red. This is now a side issue.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things a little, I have divided the **Hybrid loss** into four separate functions: Tversky's loss, Dice coefficient, Dice loss, Hybrid loss. You can see the code below.

```
def TverskyLoss(targets, inputs, alpha=0.5, beta=0.5, smooth=1e-16, numLabels=3):
    tversky = 0
    for index in range(numLabels):
        inputs_fl = tf.nest.flatten(inputs[..., index])
        targets_fl = tf.nest.flatten(targets[..., index])

        #True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
        TP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(inputs_fl, targets_fl))
        FP = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(inputs_fl, 1-targets_fl[0]))
        FN = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(1-inputs_fl[0], targets_fl))
       
        tversky_i = (TP + smooth) / (TP + alpha*FP + beta*FN + smooth)  
        tversky += tversky_i
    return numLabels - tversky

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-16):
    y_true_f = tf.nest.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = tf.nest.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(y_true_f, y_pred_f))
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.math.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.math.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_multilabel(y_true, y_pred, numLabels=3):
    dice=0
    for index in range(numLabels):
        dice -= dice_coef(y_true[..., index], y_pred[..., index])
    return numLabels + dice

def build_hybrid_loss(_lambda_=0.5, _alpha_=0.5, _beta_=0.5, smooth=1e-16, C=3):
    def hybrid_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        tversky = TverskyLoss(y_true, y_pred, alpha=_alpha_, beta=_beta_)
        dice = dice_coef_multilabel(y_true, y_pred)    
        result = tversky + _lambda_ * dice
        return result
    return hybrid_loss
```

Adding the `loss=build_hybrid_loss()` during model compilation will add Hybrid loss as the loss function of the model.

After a short research, I came to the conclusion that in my particular case, a Hybrid loss with `_lambda_ = 0.2, _alpha_ = 0.5, _beta_ = 0.5` would not be much better than a single Dice loss or a single Tversky loss. Neither IoU (intersection over union) nor the standard accuracy metric are much better with Hybrid loss. But I believe it is not a rule of thumb that such a Hybrid loss will be worser or at the same level of performance as single loss at all cases.

[link to Accuracy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR6xL.png)

[link to IoU graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX8Pu.png)